# override the header and footer glow

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Is there any ways to override the header and footer glow in the listview and custom colors/gradient while using actionbarsherlock? or can it be overridden without using actionbarsherlock?

Answer (score 0):

From what i know there is no way to do that. For more information see here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/i5a3uNN8jpg